# Syncing files between OS X and a server

Tags: macos, software-rec, backup, sync, sftp

Dropbox is pretty handy, but I want to accomplish a similar thing on a larger scale - syncing my local files across computers and on a server. I already have a big fat research server with a big drive available via SFTP (also it's useful to have my files available on the server). There must be a program to keep directories in sync with a server that just works.

1. OS X support
2. Minimal CPU/memory usage (My MacBook Pro is kindof sluggish as is)
3. Don't need admin access on the server
4. minimal setup time/cost

Comment: Have you tried `rsync`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Unix utility called [`rsync`](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html).

For synchronizing a folder to your remote host, use a simple command like:

```
rsync local-folder user@remote-machine:/remote/folder/
```

The `local-folder` will be created in `/remote/folder`.

---

`rsync` has several options you will probably want to use (see the manual for more details):

- `-a` enables archive mode
- `-v` enables more verbose output
- `-n` enables a "dry run", i.e. a fake backup
- `--delete` will delete everything on the remote host that doesn't exist locally anymore (use with caution)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thanks for your helpful answer! It would be nice to have more context, maybe explaining how to use a tool and link to an official resource. I edited your post to include that and hope you don't mind.

Comment: @slhck Wow... next time, post as your own answer and get the rep you deserve ;)

Comment: @Daniel I don't particularly need it and I think it's always helpful to poke new users in the right direction with positive reinforcement :P